# Determine if a string is a valid wchar_t* in C

Tags: c, string, wchar-t

I'm trying to recode a part of printf.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
int ret = printf("%S\n", "我是一只猫。");
printf("Printf returned %d\n", ret);
```

If the format is *%s*, printf writes the wide characters and returns 19.

If the format is *%S*, printf returns -1 because the argument is not a wide string (no *L* before *""*).

In my own implementation of printf, how can I determine if the string passed in parameter is wide, so I can return -1 if it isn't ?

**Edit**

- I'm programming on OS X El Capitan (but I would have like a portable solution if it were possible)
- In my programming environment, %S and %ls are the same - it doesn't really matter for my question here
- Printf also returns -1 when I don't set a locale for the example with format %s. This is the only reason why I've set a locale.
- I'm compiling with clang (*Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)*)

Comment: you should include OS and compiler in your question to help readers of your question to answer better

Comment: When you don't set a locale, the program behaves as if the locale has been set to `"C"`. In this case `%s` etc. should work just fine, only the wide-character variants don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you can't. Passing something that is not a wide-string for `%S` is *undefined behaviour,* anything can happen, including dæmons flying out of your nose. You are lucky that `printf` catches that, likely it detects that the contents of `"我是一只猫。"` when interpreted as an array of `wchar_t` aren't all valid codepoints (if that happens, `errno` is set to `EILSEQ` by `printf`).

Answer (score 2):

> In my own implementation of printf, how can I determine if the string passed in parameter is wide, so I can return -1 if it isn't ?

You cannot. The `%S`  format specifier is documented in [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) as

> (Not in C99 or C11, but in SUSv2, SUSv3, and SUSv4.)  Synonym
>                 for `%ls`.  Don't use.

so you should probably not use it (since it is *not* in the C11 standard, but in SUSv4). And if you did use it for your own `printf`, it would be a *promise* that the corresponding actual argument *is* a wide string.

You might however, if your C compiler is a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use an appropriate `format`  [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) (it is a GCC extension) in your declaration of your `printf` (or likewise) function. This would give warnings to the users of ill-typed arguments to your function. And you could even customize GCC (e.g. using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) by defining your own function attribute which would enable extra type-checking at compile time, so there is no portable way, given a pointer to something, to check *at runtime* if it is a pointer to a string or to something else (like an array of integers).

At runtime, your `printf`  would use [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) facilities so would have to "interpret" the format string to handle appropriately the various format specifiers. Without compiler support (à la `__attribute__((format(printf,1,2)))` in GCC (also [supported by Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#format-gnu-format)), or with your own function attribute) you cannot get any *compile-time* type checking for variadic functions. And the type information is erased in C at runtime.

Look also at *existing* implementation of `printf` like functions in [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) implementations of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). The [`stdio/vfprintf.c`](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vfprintf.c) file of [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) is quite readable.

Also, [GNU libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring) has some [elementary string checks functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html#Elementary-string-checks) like e.g. `u16_check`  which checks if an array (whose size is given) of 16 bits integers is a valid UTF16 string. Notice that `"我是一只猫。"` in UTF8 is *not* a zero-doublebyte or zero-widechar terminated UTF16 string (so simply computing its length as `wchar_t*` wide string is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because of [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)!) and might not even have the required alignment for wide strings.

Comment: Why do you assume that OP is programming for Linux? OP might be programming for a system where `%S` is the only way to get the desired effect.

Comment: I don't assume Linux,  but I trust the documentation saying that `%S` is not C11 standardized

Comment: SUSv4 is a perfectly cromulent standard. Why do you assume that OP is programming strictly against C11 when he clearly operates outside of the realm of ISO 9899:2011 (e.g. by setting a locale not mentioned in the standard)?